# Passing data from object in controller to model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm building a stock management system that consists of a product table with a quantity value that has many transactions to record how stock was added to the system.

Once a transaction is created the quantity (stock on hand) on the product table needs to be recalculated. I'm looking for best way to do this

```
current_product = Product.find_by_id(product_id)
transaction = current_product.transactions.create(
                                            :qty => 10,
                                            :value => 5.00,                                         
                                            )
#once a transaction has been created it needs to reclcuate the SOH value at the SKU level
current_product.update_stock_on_hand(transaction.id)
```

I'm not sure how to write the `update_stock_on_hand` method in the product model. Currently, it looks up the transaction id that has just been created and gets the qty value that needs to be changed.

Should the result of `update_stock_on_hand` be passed back to the controller and saved there or can I do it all in the model? If it is the latter what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

first, I think that `transaction` is a bad name to give to anything between classes, variables, etc. because transaction is a reserved word for rails and I think it's a good idea to avoid it.

About your question: there's more than one option to deal with that, I would use a callback on your `transaction` model. Since I believe you have a `has_many` relationship between `Product` and `Transaction` and you would have `product_id` attribute on your `Transaction` object as `foreign_key`, you could do something like this:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
    after_create :dispense_product

    def dispense_product
        self.product.update_attribute(:in_stock, product.in_stock - self.qty)
    end
end
```

Consider `in_stock` the attribute that holds the quantity of that product that you have in stock. What happens here is that, every time you create a transaction object like you described above, you will update the product object with the current quantity - the quantity you have dispensed. The `self` inside the method `dispense_product` refers to the `Transaction` object just created.

Hope to have helped you!